# How do I get the report from lintcmd.Run()

Tags: go, linter, cicd

I want to do some check by using `linter`.

My base require module is

```
    "honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/lint"
    "honnef.co/go/tools/lintcmd"
    "honnef.co/go/tools/simple"
    "honnef.co/go/tools/staticcheck"
    "honnef.co/go/tools/stylecheck"
    "honnef.co/go/tools/unused"
```

And I register it with the following code:

```
    var cs []*lint.Analyzer
    cs = append(cs, simple.Analyzers...)
    cs = append(cs, staticcheck.Analyzers...)
    cs = append(cs, stylecheck.Analyzers...)
    cs = append(cs, unused.Analyzer)

    lin := lintcmd.NewCommand("test")
    lin.AddAnalyzers(cs...)
```

And then, when I run it with

```
    lin.Run()
```

I can get some output like :

```
hello.go:141:2: should replace loop with b = append(b, a...) (S1011)
```

But we have a ci/cd system, we want to get the report from code check, but I didn't find any way to get the output after do `lin.Run()`, I do more dig and found the source code has a comment like:

> // Run runs all registered analyzers and reports their findings.
> // It always calls os.Exit and does not return.
> func (cmd *Command) Run() { ...}

So, How do i get the output from a function which call `os.Exit` ?

## PS

After google for a while, someone said I can captureOutput by redirect `stdout` all code like the below:

```
func captureOutput(f func()) string {
    reader, writer, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    stdout := os.Stdout
    stderr := os.Stderr
    defer func() {
        os.Stdout = stdout
        os.Stderr = stderr
        log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
    }()
    os.Stdout = writer
    os.Stderr = writer
    log.SetOutput(writer)
    out := make(chan string)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        wg.Done()
        io.Copy(&buf, reader)
        out <- buf.String()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    f()
    writer.Close()
    return <-out
}
```

But, When I tried with normally return, it works good, however when i tried to call `os.Exit` it doesn't.

```
    s := captureOutput(func() {
        fmt.Println("test fmt 1")
        os.Stderr.WriteString("test stderr 1\n")
        fmt.Println("test fmt 2")
        fmt.Println("test fmt 3")
        log.Println("test log 1")
        //os.Exit(0)
    })
    fmt.Println("s-->", s)
```

Comment: IMO the path of least resistance is to run staticcheck as a sub-process via "os/exec". This makes capturing the output relatively easy and uses the tool exactly as it is intended to be used. The next least resistance option if you really want to keep this in the same process is to fork the Run function you are trying to use. You can get this from either go-tools/lintcmd/cmd.go in staticcheck or https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/master:go/analysis/internal/checker/checker.go. For the latter you need to be okay with dropping severity and not using a CumulativeChecker.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do with `wg` in the PS. The `wg.Wait()` can resume immediately after the `wg.Done()`. I do not see a reason it cannot safely be removed.